# Growl notifications for new StackOverflow questions

Tags: discussion, osx

I'd like to get Growl notifications of new questions on Stack in my favourite tags? Is there something for this out there already?

If not, are there any good suggestion what to use for API to get this data?

Answer (score 2):

On stackapps.com I see [3 applications tagged with Growl](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/growl). All these apps generally use the [Stacks Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/). There are many more listed on http://stackapps.com, the API support site.

Personally, I use [Newt](https://stackapps.com/questions/1993/newt-question-answer-and-comment-and-rep-change-notifications-for-mac-os-x); it works a treat!

You can configure it to monitor multiple Stack Exchange sites, and it'll notify you of changes in reputation and responses as well as watch for new questions with specific tags. It also has a "Silent Mode" (only notify you of reputation changes and comments), and "Sleep" mode (no notifications at all).

Answer (score 1):

This feature isn't built in to Stack Overflow. However, you could create a browser extension (example [Chrome Extension](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)) that, at regular intervals, queries your favorite tags using the [Stack Overflow API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) and generate [HTML5 notifications](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/notifications/quick/) .

This way, even if Stack Overflow isn't open on your browser, you will get a notification letting you know of the questions that have been posted.